# How to reset nftable counter?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, nftables

It's really painful to use nftable.  I have an ipv4 table and a input chain in it.

```
table ip filter { # handle 7
    chain input { # handle 1
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        ip daddr 192.168.0.102 counter packets 697173 bytes 850761603 # handle 5
        ip saddr 192.168.0.100 counter packets 38 bytes 4096 # handle 6
    }
}
```

But how can I reset counter for handle 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to reset an *anonymous* counter (same problem as not possible to reset an *anonymous* quota, see at the end).

### Named counters

Tested with nftables 0.9.0. Required: nftables >= 0.8 and kernel >= 4.10.

What can be done instead is to use *named* counters, which are one of the (currently) three possible [stateful objects](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/nftables/nft.8#STATEFUL_OBJECTS): *counter*, (conntrack) *helper* and *quota* . These named counters can then be referenced from rules. A given named counter is attached to a table. OP's ruleset can be written like this instead:

```
table ip filter {
    counter mycounterd102 {
        packets 697173 bytes 850761603
    }
    counter mycounters100 {
        packets 38 bytes 4096
    }
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        ip daddr 192.168.0.102 counter name "mycounterd102"
        ip saddr 192.168.0.100 counter name "mycounters100"
    }
}
```

With a manual *nft* command the named counter is created like this, optionally with non zero values set:

```
nft add counter ip filter mycounterd102 packets 697173 bytes 850761603
```

Now, one can list or reset these named counters:

```
# nft list counter ip filter mycounterd102
table ip filter {
    counter mycounterd102 {
        packets 697173 bytes 850761603
    }
}
# nft reset counter ip filter mycounterd102
table ip filter {
    counter mycounterd102 {
        packets 697173 bytes 850761603
    }
}
# nft list counter ip filter mycounterd102
table ip filter {
    counter mycounterd102 {
        packets 0 bytes 0
    }
}
```

As expected the reset command will atomically list-and-reset the given counter.

It's also possible to reset all counters in the table (or in all tables if no table is given):

```
# nft reset counters table ip filter
table ip filter {
    counter mycounters100 {
        packets 38 bytes 4096
    }
    counter mycounterd102 {
        packets 0 bytes 0
    }
}
```

Reference: [Stateful objects - nftables wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Stateful_objects#Resetting_stateful_objects)

which talks about counters and quotas. There's a linked bug related to not being able to reset an anonymous quota even if resetting all quotas. One can suppose it's exactly the same issue with counters: not available as of january 2019 (and at the date of this answer):

[Bug 1314 - nft reset quotas does not reset anonymous quotas](https://bugzilla.netfilter.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1314)

Comment: Great detailed answer, +1.  If you happen to have a little more depth of knowledge about counters, I have this question I'm looking for help with... https://serverfault.com/questions/1018654/where-are-nftables-counters-logged-stored-and-how-long-to-they-persist

Comment: Resetting anonymous counters might become available with future kernel 6.2 or 6.3: https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netfilter-devel/patch/20221014214559.22254-2-phil@nwl.cc/ "Add a 'reset' flag just like with nft_object_ops::dump. This will be
useful to **reset "anonymous stateful objects", e.g. simple rule counters**.
"

Comment: `nft add counter ip filter mycounterd102` how to add comment to counter in this syntax?

Comment: @metablaster there's an example with a comment in the wiki: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Counters#Declaring_and_using_named_counters .

Comment: @metablaster or description of the syntax in the man page: https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#COUNTER