# Where are nftables counters logged/stored, and how long do they persist?

Tags: networking, logging, traffic, nftables, accounting

I'm attempting to track the total data being transmitted from a specific set of IP addresses (both IPv4 and IPv6) using `nftables` with a named `counter` on the rule. My goal is to be able to track this total over the course of a calendar month so I can bill against usage.

The related rules look like this:

```
add table stats
add counter stats os-traffic-4
add counter stats os-traffic-6
add chain inet stats INPUT { type filter hook input priority 0; }
add rule ip  stats INPUT ip  saddr 192.168.123.123 counter name os-traffic-4
add rule ip  stats INPUT ip  saddr 192.168.123.234 counter name os-traffic-4
add rule ip  stats INPUT ip  saddr 192.168.123.345 counter name os-traffic-4
add rule ip6 stats INPUT ip6 saddr 1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234 counter name os-traffic-6
add rule ip6 stats INPUT ip6 saddr 1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:2345 counter name os-traffic-6
add rule ip6 stats INPUT ip6 saddr 1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:3456 counter name os-traffic-6
```

I'm using `stateful objects` (named counters) to sum all of the traffic from the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses respectively, named `os-traffic-4` and `os-traffic-6`.  I can then use the command line to get those stats with `nft list counter stats os-traffic-6`.

**My questions are:**

1. Where are these stats stored, I don't see them in a log anywhere and can't find reference in any documentation?
2. Will these statistics persist past a reboot of the machine or will the counters reset?
3. If they do reset, how do I restore them at boot time?  I believe it's possible to include the counter values when using `add rule... packets 1234 bytes 123456` but how do I do it for a named counter and also... #1... where do I get these numbers from?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

I believe that `nftables` counters are stored in kernel memory only, similar to tables and rules. They may not persist across reboots.

My suggestion to keep permanent record of the counter values is to:

- Declare your counters in a separate file and include it from your main `nftables` configuration file.
- Have the counter declaration file updated with current values.

Depending on the distribution you are using, you may have a `nftables.service` unit that loads rules from a configuration file. If so, you can design a service that depends of `nftables.service` and writes counter values to the state file. For example, in Arch Linux, the `nftables.service` is designed to load firewall rules from `/etc/nftables.conf`, so you could define these configuration files:

```
# /etc/nftables.conf

add table stats

# Counter definitions go to '/var/lib/nftables.state'
include "/var/lib/nftables.state"

add chain inet stats INPUT { type filter hook input priority 0; }
add rule ip  stats INPUT ip  saddr 192.168.123.123 counter name os-traffic-4
add rule ip  stats INPUT ip  saddr 192.168.123.234 counter name os-traffic-4
add rule ip  stats INPUT ip  saddr 192.168.123.345 counter name os-traffic-4
add rule ip6 stats INPUT ip6 saddr 1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234 counter name os-traffic-6
add rule ip6 stats INPUT ip6 saddr 1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:2345 counter name os-traffic-6
add rule ip6 stats INPUT ip6 saddr 1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:3456 counter name os-traffic-6
```

```
# /var/lib/nftables.state

add counter stats os-traffic-4
add counter stats os-traffic-6
```

```
# /etc/systemd/system/nftables-persist-counters.service

[Unit]
BindsTo=nftables.service
After=nftables.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/nft list counters > /var/lib/nftables.state'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

**EDIT:** The `systemctl reload nftables.service` command shall be blocked for the automatic counter storage to work. Therefore, deployment of an additional file is required:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/nftables.service.d/block-systemctl-reload.conf

[Service]
ExecReload=
```

Comment: Great idea using the state file. Really look forward to trying this out tonight, very much appreciate the effort here, thank you!